# Unable to Selectall/Deselectall using master checkbox in html table

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

[image]

I have shared my html and ts code below , here I can select and deselect multiple rows in table ,but the problem is I dont know how to SELECTALL/DESELECTALL using master checkbox

My code is reproduced in the below url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bbx9jh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

HTML

```
<div class="card-body">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table  class="table">
      <thead class=" text-primary">
          <th>
             <input type="checkbox">
          </th>
          <th>
             Product Name
          </th>
          <th>
              Cost
          </th>
          <!-- <th>
              City
          </th>
          <th>
              Salary
          </th> -->
      </thead>
      <tbody>

          <tr *ngFor = "let data of productDataMultipleValue; let j = index;">
              <td>  
                <span style="padding-left:20px;
              ">             
          <input type="checkbox" [checked]="data.checker" 
    (change)="checkboxMultiplier(data,$event,j)"></span></td>
              <td >
                  <span style="padding-left:140px;
              ">{{data.namer}}</span>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <span style="padding-left:40px;
              ">{{data.coster}}</span>
              </td>
              <!-- <td>
                  {{}}
              </td>
              <td class="text-primary">
                 {{}}
              </td> -->
          </tr>

      </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Now below you can find the Typescript part of my code

TS

```
saveMultiRows: any = [];
productDataMultipleValue: any = [
{"id":1,"namer":"wires","coster":25},
{"id":1,"namer":"pipes","coster":40},
{"id":1,"namer":"motors","coster":67},
{"id":1,"namer":"lights","coster":78},
{"id":1,"namer":"switches","coster":86}
]


checkboxMultiplier(rowObj: any,event: any,rowIndex: any) {


let temp = 
  {  "namer":rowObj.namer,
  "coster" : rowObj.coster}

  if (event.target.checked == true) {

 
   this.saveMultiRows.push(temp);

    } else if (event.target.checked == false) {

    for (let j = 0; j < this.saveMultiRows.length; j++ ){
    if (this.saveMultiRows[j].coster == rowObj.coster) {
      this.saveMultiRows.splice(j,1);
    }
    }     
    }

console.log(this.saveMultiRows);
```

}

My code is reproduced in the below url
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bbx9jh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

thanks for providing the stackblitz link.

I have tweaked your code a bit you can check it in the link below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b6o69x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks,it works but i face a small issue which is after selecting all checkboxes using master checkbox,when i deselect it removes the entire row

Comment: It works fine now satisfying all condition thanks

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, what you have to do is, add an `onclick EventListener` to the topmost checkbox (The one which you will use for select / deselect all) and then, the pseudocode is something like:

- `onclick` Topmost checkbox,
- Select all checkboxes with jQuery `$("input:checkbox")` and
- Set the `isChecked` property of the topmost checkbox to all the checkboxes

I am not familiar with `TypeScript` but this is the way it is done with `JavaScript and jQuery`

```
$("#topCheckbox").click(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

**I assumed you will add `id=topCheckbox` to your main checkbox which you are using for select / deselect all**

Comment: I have not used jquery, i will give it a try,Thanks